# non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context Dormitory dormitory = new Dormitory();

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I’m a beginner self-teaching Java Programmer. I’m trying to perfect my knowledge of OOPS and I’ve been trying to get pass this modifier issue in the past couple of days.

Please I need someone to peruse and explain to me what I’m doing wrong and how I should do it right.

**CODE**

```
class Student {
  int studentId;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  char gender;
  int age;
  String nationality;

Student(){
    System.out.println("Student Record");
}

void setStudentDetails(int studentId, String firstName, String lastName, char gender, int age, String nationality){
this.studentId = studentId;
this.firstName = firstName;
this.lastName = lastName;
this.gender = gender;
this.age = age;
this.nationality = nationality;
}

void showStudentDetails(){
    System.out.println("Student ID: " + studentId);
    System.out.println("First Name: " + firstName);
    System.out.println("Last Name: " + lastName);
    System.out.println("Gender: " + gender);
    System.out.println("Age : " + age);
    System.out.println("Nationality: " + nationality);
}

class Contact extends Student {
  String fullAddress;
  String postalAddress;
  long phoneNumber;
  String email;
  String nextOfKin;
  String nextOfKinAddress;
  long nextOfKinPhoneNumber;

void setStudentDetails(int studentId, String firstName, String lastName, char gender, int age, String nationality, String fullAddress, String postalAddress, long phoneNumber, String email, String nextOfKin, String nextOfKinAddress, long nextOfKinPhoneNumber){
    
this.studentId = studentId;
this.firstName = firstName;
this.lastName = lastName;
this.gender = gender;
this.age = age;
this.nationality = nationality;
this.fullAddress = fullAddress;
this.postalAddress = postalAddress;
this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
this.email = email;
this.nextOfKin = nextOfKin;
this.nextOfKinAddress = nextOfKinAddress;
this.nextOfKinPhoneNumber = nextOfKinPhoneNumber;
}

void showStudentDetails(){
    System.out.println("Student ID: " + studentId);
    System.out.println("First Name: " + firstName);
    System.out.println("Last Name: " + lastName);
    System.out.println("Gender: " + gender);
    System.out.println("Age : " + age);
    System.out.println("Nationality: " + nationality);
    System.out.println("Full Address: " + fullAddress);
    System.out.println("Postal Address: " + postalAddress);
    System.out.println("Phone Number: " + phoneNumber);
    System.out.println("Enail: " + email);
    System.out.println("Next of Kin: " + nextOfKin);
    System.out.println("Next of Kin Address: " + nextOfKinAddress);
    System.out.println("Next of Kin Phone Number: " + nextOfKinPhoneNumber);
}
}

class Dormitory extends Student {

  String hallName;
  int dormFloor;
  String dormWing;
  int dormRoomNum;
  int bunkNum;

void setStudentDetails(int studentId, String firstName, String lastName, char gender, int age, String nationality, String fullAddress, String postalAddress, long phoneNumber, String email, String nextOfKin, String nextOfKinAddress, long nextOfKinPhoneNumber, String hallName,int dormFloor,String dormWing,int dormRoomNum,int bunkNum){
    
this.studentId = studentId;
this.firstName = firstName;
this.lastName = lastName;
this.gender = gender;
this.age = age;
this.nationality = nationality;
this.hallName = hallName;
this.dormFloor = dormFloor;
this.dormWing = dormWing;
this.dormRoomNum = dormRoomNum;
this.bunkNum = bunkNum;
}

void showStudentDetails(){
  System.out.println("Student ID: " + studentId);
  System.out.println("First Name: " + firstName);
  System.out.println("Last Name: " + lastName);
  System.out.println("Gender: " + gender);
  System.out.println("Age : " + age);
  System.out.println("Nationality: " + nationality);
  System.out.println("Dormitory: " + hallName);
  System.out.println("Dormitory Floor: " + dormFloor);
  System.out.println("Floor Wing: " + dormWing);
  System.out.println("Room Number: " + dormRoomNum);
  System.out.println("Bunk Number: " + bunkNum);
}
}

public static void main(String[] args){
  Dormitory dormitory = new Dormitory();
    dormitory.setStudentDetails(001,"David","Olawuyi",'M', 29, "Nigerian","2 Glover Road, Lagos", "Same as Full Address", 9045356445L,"lol@yahoo.com","Philip Olawuyi","2 Glover Road, Lagos",8074637483L,"King Hall",2,"D",35,3);
    dormitory.showStudentDetails();
}
}
```

JVM Output: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
Dormitory dormitory = new Dormitory();

Comment: Your classes need to be static!?

Comment: Hi David and welcome to SO. A good idea that will help you and also help us to help you is to take some time and try to correctly format/indent you code so that it renders nicely in your question.

Comment: @luk2302 by declaring my Dormitory class as static class Dormitory extends Student{}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this error is that `Dormitory` is defined as an [inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) of `Student`. This means that each `Dormitory` is contained in a `Student`, and needs to be created with a containing `Student`.

This code compiles:

```
Dormitory dormitory = new Student().new Dormitory();
```

However, this is probably not the way you would want to design this program. Logically, dormitories are not contained in students. You also wouldn't want to create `Student` as an inner class of `Dormitory`. Even though you might consider dormitories to contain students, in Java, you can't reassign an instance of an inner class to a different instance of an outer class, so it's better to define these as separate top-level classes. Same with `Contact`. Alternatively, you could define them as [static nested classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html), but I would recommend starting with top-level classes.

In this code `Dormitory` also `extends Student`, which is not a usual way to design object-oriented programs. Inheritance is meant to model an "is-a" relationship, so saying `class Dormitory extends Student` in Java is like saying "a dormitory is a student" in English. More likely, you would say "a dormitory *has a* student" (or maybe more than one). You can represent this by giving the `Dormitory` a field of type `Student` and assigning it to the student occupying the bunk:

```
class Dormitory {
    String hallName;
    int dormFloor;
    String dormWing;
    int dormRoomNum;
    int bunkNum;
    Student occupant; // Added field

    void setDormitoryDetails(String hallName, int dormFloor, String dormWing, int dormRoomNum, int bunkNum, Student occupant) {
        this.hallName = hallName;
        this.dormFloor = dormFloor;
        this.dormWing = dormWing;
        this.dormRoomNum = dormRoomNum;
        this.bunkNum = bunkNum;
        this.occupant = occupant;
    }

    void showStudentDetails() {
        System.out.println("Student ID: " + occupant.studentId);
        System.out.println("First Name: " + occupant.firstName);
        System.out.println("Last Name: " + occupant.lastName);
        System.out.println("Gender: " + occupant.gender);
        System.out.println("Age : " + occupant.age);
        System.out.println("Nationality: " + occupant.nationality);
        System.out.println("Dormitory: " + hallName);
        System.out.println("Dormitory Floor: " + dormFloor);
        System.out.println("Floor Wing: " + dormWing);
        System.out.println("Room Number: " + dormRoomNum);
        System.out.println("Bunk Number: " + bunkNum);
    }
}
```

This can be used from `main` like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dormitory dormitory = new Dormitory();
    Contact student = new Contact();
    student.setStudentDetails(001,"David","Olawuyi",'M', 29, "Nigerian","2 Glover Road, Lagos", "Same as Full Address", 9045356445L,"lol@yahoo.com","Philip Olawuyi","2 Glover Road, Lagos",8074637483L);
    dormitory.setDormitoryDetails("King Hall", 2, "D", 35, 3, student);
    dormitory.showStudentDetails();
}
```

If it were my program, there are some other changes I'd make:

- Have each class accept the fields as constructor arguments rather than one big set method
- Make each field `private` and add getter methods
- Rename `Contact` to `ContactDetails` and make each student have a `ContactDetails` field, rather than having `Contact` extend `Student`
- Rename `Dormitory` to `DormitoryAssignment`, since I think that is a more accurate description of what data it contains ("dormitory" can imply an entire building)
- Move the `main` method out of `Student` to a separate application class named for what the overall program is intended to do

Comment: I appreciate the correction and suggestions Tim, this will help me improve as beginner.